# AWS EC2 Python ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

I am using an EC2 instance with Deep Learning AMI based on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am doing the following:

- Start the terminal
- Activate the conda environment: `conda activate tensorflow2_latest_p37`
- Install the package `pip3 install tensorrt`
- Run my code `python3 mycode.py`

And I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorrt'
```

I also trying to install as *sudo* or with *-U* or *-m* option. Nothing work. I can't install with *conda install* because tensorrt is not available in it.

Answer (score 0):

`pip3` will use ubuntu's level pip3, not from anaconda. You can confirm this by using `which pip3` after you activate your environemnt.  ALso `tensorrt` is [not available](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html) for python other then 3.6

So to [install](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-pip) `tensorrt` on Ubuntu 18.04 Deep Learnig:

```
conda activate tensorflow2_p36

# then in tensorflow2_p36 environment

pip install nvidia-pyindex
pip install --upgrade nvidia-tensorrt
```